# I am receiving an incompatible type error?

Tags: java, list, hyperlink

```
public class Node<X> {

    private X value;
    private Node link;

    public X getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Node getLink() {
        return link;
    }    
}
```

.

```
public X get(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        Node i = head;
        int c = 0;

        while (c < index)
        {
            i = i.getLink();
            c++;
        }

        return i.getValue();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

When i compile. it says incompatible types, why though? getValue is type X, get returns X, and i.getValue(); is an X, but shows incompatible type error, what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
   Node i = head;
```

Needs to be

```
   Node<X> i = head;
```

Otherwise `getValue()` returns an `Object`.

Also, in your `Node` class:

```
private Node<X> link;
```

and

```
public Node<X> getLink() {
```